# How to add class in a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, class

I would like to put class inside this string :

```
 <div class="date-custom-page">   
      <?php
        $date = get_field('jour_de_levenement', false, false);
        $time = strtotime($date);
      ?>

      <?php $dateformatstring = "<p class='date-event'>j</p><p class='month'>F Y</p>"; ?>
      <?php $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('jour_de_levenement', false, false));

    echo date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp); ?>
```

I have tried this but only the p is taken, not the class. 
Can someone help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: WFM https://3v4l.org/ueLS2 Though you should really put classes in quotes.

Comment: why not simply `$dateformatstring = "<p class='date-event'>j</p><p class='month'>F Y</p>";` ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers, I've tried every of your solutions but it doesn't seem to work. It's really strange because on the frontend I see that my p doesn't take the class. 
It gives me something like that : <p 2016-10-15t07:00:00+00:00zaterdagam0000="15am31Europe/Brusse‌​ls-Europe/Brussels00‌​0Europe/Brussels1031‌​">15</p>

Do you have any idea ? 

Thanks

Comment: @FlorianeA Then what you've given us isn't accurate. Show us _all_ relevant _real_ code. What you've given us to show your "problem" doesn't have the problem you say.

Comment: Ugh... you've passed that string through `date` haven't you...

Comment: Please go read the [date](http://php.net/date) documentation. Various characters get swapped out as it expects a string that defines an output format, not a literal content string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this :

```
$dateformatstring = "<p class='date-event'>j</p><p class='month'>F Y</p>";
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick answer but there is something really strange, here is what it displays on the frontend : 
<p 2016-10-15t07:00:00+00:00zaterdagam0000="15am31Europe/Brussels-Europe/Brussels000Europe/Brussels1031">15</p>

Do you have any idea ?